# Deploy BizTalk Application via MSBuild

Tags: .net, msbuild, biztalk, biztalk-2009, biztalk-deployment

I am trying to setup up a continuous integration type environment for BizTalk. When source code is checked in, I need it to build then deploy to a build server. I have found BTSTask.exe but this seems to only be able to install an application from an existing msi.

I need a way of basically doing what visual studio does when you right click on the project and say deploy. Has anyone encountered a way of a doing this via MSBuild or some other way?

Answer (score 4):

A few years back I switched over to using the [BizTalk Deployment Framework](http://biztalkdeployment.codeplex.com/) and haven't looked back.  It uses MSBuild and WIX in building the perfect way to handle deployments for BizTalk.  I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use MSBuild ExtensionPack there will be MSBuild.ExtensionPack.BizTalk Namespace, here you can find it: http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/

Another tool is Microsoft Sdc Tasks which has a huge functionality: http://sdctasks.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

BTSTask supports adding resources (i.e. dlls) directly; check out the [MSDN documentation for the AddResource command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560955%28v=BTS.10%29.aspx).

Check out [Sayeds answer to a similar question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472183/replace-sln-with-msbuild-and-wrap-contained-projects-into-targets) and [my answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067307/good-practices-how-to-reuse-csproj-and-sln-files-to-create-your-msbuild-script/3071804#3071804) after I implemented and improved Sayeds suggestion.

For some tasks BTSTask isn't powerful enough so you'll have to use `Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM` from within PowerShell scripts as I suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149770/btstask-and-btscontrol-for-biztalk-2009/3159420#3159420).

I did not look into TFS yet an how much it supports BizTalk deployment out-of-the-box.

If you are interested I'll add a complete sample MSBuild .proj.

Answer (score 0):

We use the IDE (devenv.exe) to compile then a series of BTSTask commands to deploy to BizTalk.  The full process is documented here:

http://blog.kynetix.com/2009/12/15/automated-testing-with-biztalk-server-3/

Hope that helps.

-Krip